# Can't reference to newly added layout in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I wanna point out that i'm a total newbie in Xamarin.

My goal is to create simple app that after you push the button, it will jump to another layout. My problem is, that after i created a new layout(called layout1) and new activity, I can't reference to this layout in my MainActivity.

freshly created Activity:

```
namespace Layouts
{
    [Activity(Label = "Activity1")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

        }
    }
}
```

And my MainActivity:

```
namespace Layouts
{
    [Activity(Label = "Layouts", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
            button1.Click += delegate
            {
              StartActivity(typeof(layout1)); //can't reference layout1 there
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be great, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));
```

Comment: Add some comments to your answer

Comment: There is no comments. Instead of StartActivity(typeof(layout1)); use StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));